# Azure function Service bus topic trigger sleeps

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am working on **Service bus topic trigger function**. we have used **consumption plan**. It is observed that the **function goes to sleep** after inactivity and it **does not wake up when there is new message** on topic.

Function is deployed using pipeline using arm templates and we are not making any changes after deployment.

Same issue is discussed in multiple discussions.

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/229

Probable solution is at below location.
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/210

But not sure what needs to be done as developer here. Can someone please help in here?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi Nelion, did not get any solution for this one.